# Undefined HTML object when summing HTML DOM elements(object HTMLUnknownElement)

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I am trying to display the sub-total of 6 line-cost elements found in a HTML/php webpage file. I have done this through iterating all 6 elements dynamically, unfortunately all 6 elements are displayed as "undefined[object HTMLUnknownElement]" instead of one single sum in the sub-total. 
Could I be missing some sort of value conversion?

My JavaScript is found here below:

```
function findSubTotal(){
  var i;
  var sum;
  let p = document.getElementsByTagName("line_cost");

  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + p[i];
  }

  setSubTotal(sum, "sub_total");
}


function setSubTotal(sum, item_id){
  let i = document.getElementById(item_id);
  i.innerHTML = sum;
  findDeliveryCharge();
}
```

[The error being displayed on the php page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epmlx.png)

Comment: because sum is undefined.... `var sum;` <-- same as `var sum = undefined;` And than you do `sum = undefined + p[i]` on the first iteration. Next issue, you are adding DOM element together.... I highly doubt you want to add elements together.... So you should be reading it's text.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below,

```
function findSubTotal(){
  var i;
  var sum = 0; // initialize the sum
  let p = document.getElementsByTagName("line_cost");

  for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (!isNaN(Number(p[i].innerHTML))) {
       sum = Number(sum + Number(p[i].innerHTML)); // p[i].innerHTML gives you the value
    }

  }

  setSubTotal(sum, "sub_total");
}


function setSubTotal(sum, item_id){
  let i = document.getElementById(item_id);
  i.innerHTML = sum;
  findDeliveryCharge();
}
```

Comment: And that is now going to be "01212312387612876182736182736"

Comment: yes use the Number(p[i].innerHTML), like that in the loop, I have updated the code.

Comment: You can give the condition in for loop, if value, is Number then only do the sum. if(  !isNaN( Number(p[i].innerHTML )) ) { sum = sum +Number(p[i].innerHTML); }